# How to insert a string variable inside the text message in a Label?

Tags: python, tkinter

How to insert a string value inside a text input for a label in tkinter ~ python script.

For Eg:

```
label = Label(master, text="Hello %s ! Welcome Back"%(str(user_name),)
```

But still it prints PY_VAR4 or some variable like that.. Instead how can I input the value of string inside the text ?

Share in your comments. Thanks in adv.

Regards,
Vimo

Comment: @All : Well initially 
a. I declared the user_name as user_name = StringVar() and doing the above step. 
b. But after removing the StringVar declaration and tried the below code 
    label = Label(master, test = "Hello %s ! Welcome Back"% user) and it started printing the variable name

Answer (score 2):

Use `user_name.get()` to get text in text entry widget:

```
label = Label(master, text="Hello %s ! Welcome Back" % user_name.get())
```

If you want to change the label text after creating it, you can use `label.configure(text=...)` / `label.config(text=...)` or `label['text'] = ...`:

```
label.configure("Hello %s ! Welcome Back" % user_name.get())
label['text'] = "Hello %s ! Welcome Back" % user_name.get()
```

Comment: @falsetruThanks for your reply. I tried all the 3 methods but then still its not inserting the required user_name string variable inside the text :-( . Is there anything I need to import ? Or Something am I missing ? Kindly let me know the same.

Comment: @Vimo, Could you update question with working example? It's hard to guess what `user_name` means.